# Нет выбора ОС при запуске ноутбука

Tags: linux, dual-boot, manjaro

Стояли рядом Windows 10  и Manjaro Linux. После "грубой" переустановки Manjaro с долгим восстановлением загрузчика Grub, пропал выбор ОС при запуске ноутбука: запускается сразу Manjaro.

`update-grub` не помогает, вывод `efibootmgr` следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

Если EFI-файл от Windows не потерт и доступен, то `os-prober` найдет его.

```
 sudo os-prober

 sudo update-grub
```

Как вариант - попробовать [Boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/ru/). Говорят, вытаскивает систему из любого состояния.

Comment: Он, судя по описанию, прям автоматически все правит?

Comment: @AlexanderAPS Кроме этого он почти ничего не умеет. Ну как бы рабочая система, можно файлы скопировать, можно переразбить/отформатировать разделы...

Answer (score 0):

В предпоследних версиях граба OS-prober отключался по умолчанию в загрузчике, "по соображениям безопасности". Можно попробовать отредактировать /usr/bin/grub-mkconfig.
Заменив в строке

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

true на false

И выполнить `update-grub` ещё раз

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло((